# how did they create this specific voice

Tags: guide, tutorial, software

hello friends,
please give attention to my question, i need to finish my project. just now i post this question but the video didnt work well now i edit again and posted.

how did they change leonardo dicaprio voice like this??
[youtube]vaR7D3STrzs&feature[/youtube]

leonardo dicaprio original voice
[youtube]gKQmC8xDtvU&feature[/youtube]

i am willing to get any software to create this specific voice. i need this voice to tell my story in few scene. i am not sure of the keyword to find tutorial in youtube to learn how to create this specific voice. i really will appreciate if anyone give me a keyword to find tutorial to learn how to create this voice, or if u can please link me to the tutorial will teach me how to change my original voice into something like what they did to leonardo dicaprio voice.... thankx in advance, hope someone will help me.

Comment: I can't seem to find your vaR7D3STrzs clip. Do you have another link? I'm super interested in this post of yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

He is an actor. He performed it that way. They may have done some processing afterwards, anything they did is probably minimal compared to what he contributed.

Comment: i am sure there must have any software to change a normal voice like this, even we can change a normal voice to sound like t-pain voice, we even can do voice of robot like in transformer etc. why not we can change a normal voice to sound like what they did to  leonardo dicaprio voice... i am sure there is any software like audacity can do that etc

Comment: anyone can help answer my question? respect your time. thank you. and thankx in advance for others.

Comment: @bowie_rascal - because they are not using software to do it. he is acting. voice actors do this kind of stuff all the time. a good example is mark hamill playing the joker in the animated batman shows.

Comment: Bingo, Shaun. .

Answer (score 6):

The voice is, as everybody else already pointed out, clean. It is, however, not recorded on location, it's completely ADR. I even, for the sake of argument, just made the exact same voice myself, except my voice is softer. It's not hard making your voice sound like this, though it helps being a little cold.

I'm no speech trainer, but I do work a lot as both an ADR/Dubbing technician/director, locationsound recordist (mostly over-the-shoulder), and voice actor. When I direct I mostly show what I want and discuss it based on the actors own experience, I rarely try to make something out of a voice I haven't seen before as such (unless I've at least seen tendencies of it before) but I'd say that kind of voice is based on the top of the throat, giving absolutely no support from the diaphragm. To get a feel of it, try sounding like a creaking door.

Probably not the answer you wanted, but fact is that processing almost never beats using good voice-actors the first place. We are *EXTREMELY* sensitive to voices, so even small unnaturalnesses tends to be very obvious even though the same degree on a, say, car, would go completely unnoticed. For good examples, see E.T. in the movie by the same name, the predator from Predator, Duke from Fear And Loathing, and even Chewbacca from Star Wars, though his voice is an annoyed sea-lion. Waylon Smithers from Simpsons also has a similar voice to this made from the same guy, Harry Shearer, making the voices for Principal Skinner, Kent Brockman, Mr. Burns, Ned Flanders, Reverend Lovejoy, Dr. Hibbert, Lenny Leonard, Otto Mann, Rainier Wolfcastle, Dr. Marvin Monroe and many others.

Answer (score 1):

You underestimate the capability of an actor's perfomance.

It is a pity, that AFI doesn't have a category “Best 100 sound effects of all time”. I am totally sure that 99% of these effects would be unprocessed sounds. Only layering and basic editing such as cutting, volume or EQ.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Conant on this. Good actors can create some incredible 'effects' with their own voice that often need no or minimal processing. DiCaprio in has produced many different voices in his films and I think you'll find that this is 99% or even 100% his own voice.

You have to remember that not everything can be created in post!

Answer (score 1):

IRCAM tools has some badass voice formant processing plugin that supposedly works

Answer (score 1):

sound mostly like his performance though possibly pitched up or altered a tad. Antares Throat may get you a sound you are happy with, but used conservatively. Someone else mentioned IRCAM Tools as well. Basically if you are wanting to create this type of sound beyond performance you are looking at Voice formant and pitch alteration.

Answer (score 0):

This really is the actor's voice with only limited processing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else.  He is working in his upper register.

Answer (score 0):

If you look really close you'll see he's carrying a helium cylinder from which he inhales when the camera's off him. Listen hard and you can hear the hiss!

C.O.Jones